# Disable Rootless on Headless Mac

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I understand that the way to disable rootless is through the Recovery Partition. However, I have a remote, headless Mac with an attached bootable clone drive that I access via Screen Sharing. Can I either:

a) Boot into the recovery partition using the command line?

or

b) Boot into the clone and change the rootless status of the HD from there?

Answer (score 0):

If `csrutil disable` doesn't work, you can try to disable it via boot args, e.g.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"
```

then `reboot`

Comment: This does not work using OS X El Capita.