# disable SIP on a remote/headless machine running Sierra?

Tags: macos, sip

I have a remote 2012 mac mini running Sierra.  Long ago I was doing some troubleshooting and had created a secondary copy of the system on the machine.  Once I had finished whatever I was doing (which I don't even remember anymore) I got my working system running again and deleted the alternate one.  Trouble is since it contains system files, they are locked down by SIP and can't be deleted without disabling SIP.  Which of course can only be done from recovery mode, which requires having a display and keyboard attached to the machine in question.  Which I don't have.

Is there any way to:

1. Disable SIP without using recovery mode at all?  I have found other threads (such as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218152/disable-rootless-on-headless-mac) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261684/disable-sip-without-recovery-mode)) about this and the consensus appears to be "no", but I thought I would reiterate the question here to be thorough.  Or,
2. Empty the trash of protected items without having to disable SIP first?

The machine is running Sierra and SIP is definitely enabled currently (`csrutil status`).

Comment: The security behind SIP is  that  you  can't disable it without u mounting the boot volume first  and  that  requires direct "console" access. As  to  your second question, Trash isn't protected and as  far  as  items covered by  SIP, you simply cannot move then to  the Trash. So, that's  more of  an  issue. Can  you  expand  on  that  issue rather than re-ask an already answered question?

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure what you mean that SIP-protected items cannot be moved to trash.  They most certainly can... they just can't be emptied.  I moved an entire System directory to the Trash, and most of it did in fact delete, but a handful of Library files refuse to delete, giving me "Some items in the trash cannot be deleted because of SIP"

Comment: I meant they can't be  deleted.  You  did  this  with SIP enabled?

Comment: SIP shouldn't give a damn about files on a non-boot drive. They're not 'system files' they're just 'stuff on a drive'. Perms can be ignored too, so you should be able to do anything you like. If they can't be deleted it's because the current system thinks they belong to it.

Comment: @Allan Yes they were moved to trash with SIP enabled.  They were not the active system at the time, of course.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is the boot drive, hence the problem.

Comment: Did you create two systems on one partition? The files you cannot delete are being considered part of the currently booted system, otherwise you could delete them.

Comment: @Tetsujin This was years ago so I really don't remember the details. But I know I did create a second/alternate system on the drive while troubleshooting something.  I don't remember how or exactly why I did this, it might have been to test an OS update before committing to it, but I can't be sure. If these files were a part of the current system I would expect to be able to restore them via "put back", but there is no such option. Interesting observation however.

Comment: As you're not going to be able to disable SIP remotely, you might need to look into shrinking a partition to create a new one. Set up a clean OS on there & migrate user data from the borked one, or pull user data off to your local machine for safety. I don't know of any tool that could pick this apart otherwise.

Comment: It's sounding more and more like the genuine answer is simply "No, these are impossible."  I may just break down and connect a physical keyboard and display to it in order to solve this nuisance.  And that's really all it is anyway, a nuisance.  Thanks all.  And anyone who wishes to make their "no" answer an actual answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You are correct. SIP only applies to the boot volume. So another OS X or macOS installed on a different volume would not be protected by SIP. This is true when installed in a different partitions or (in the case of APFS) the same partition. The problem the OP is have probably has nothing to do with SIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disable SIP without using recovery mode at all? I have found other threads (such as here and here) about this and the consensus appears to be "no", but I thought I would reiterate the question here to be thorough.

**System Integrity Protection** cannot be disabled from a *normal mode boot* (from ones's **Desktop**). The **Apple** provided method is to use `csrutil disable` from **Terminal** while booted to **macOS Recovery**. What good would it be if it could be disabled from a *normal mode boot*? (Rhetorical question!)

As mentioned by David Anderson in a comment, one could use **rEFInd** to disable **SIP**, however, this **cannot be done** from a *normal mode boot* (from ones's **Desktop**) and would require having **rEFInd** installed and rebooting the system to **rEFInd**, which you'd have no control of from a headless-system without a keyboard.

> Empty the trash of protected items without having to disable SIP first?

From a *normal mode boot* (from one's **Desktop**), no, however one can delete the various **.Trashes** and **.Trash** *directories* from **Terminal** in **macOS Recovery** without disabling **SIP** and then reboot back to *normal mode boot* and those *directories* will be recreated.

What good would **SIP** be if one could bypass its restrictions from a *normal mode boot*? (Rhetorical question!)

Obviously, you'll need to temporarily add a *keyboard* and *monitor* to the **Mac mini** to boot to **macOS Recovery** in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, adding a keyboard and display is clearly the only way to solve this then since Recovery mode is always required.  Ah well, thanks again for the confirmation.

Comment: It is a minor point, but SIP can also be disabled using rEFInd. So booting to macOS Recovery is not the only way. Also, using rEFInd would not work on a Mac without at least a keyboard attached.

Comment: @David Anderson,  In this particular use case it's a very minor  point since it cannot be disabled from a _normal mode boot_ (from one's **Desktop**) even with **rEFInd**, and it would also have to be installed separately as it's not a part of **macOS**.

Comment: The rEFInd Boot Manager can be configured to boot from a flash drive. The rEFInd Boot Manager does not require macOS. The rEFInd Boot Manager can also be configured to allow SIP to be enabled or disabled from rEFInd. If you know the correct key sequence, then you could disable SIP without the use of a monitor, but this would require a keyboard.

Comment: @David Anderson, It's totally irrelevant from where you run **rEFInd** as it still has to be installed, it's not a part of **macOS**  and cannot disable **SIP** from _normal mode boot_ of **macOS**. That said, in this particular case  **SIP** does not even need to be disabled as the _files/folders_ can be deleted by deleting the various **.Trashes** and **.Trash** _directories_ from **Terminal** in **macOS Recovery** without disabling **SIP** and then reboot back to _normal mode boot_ and those _directories_ will be recreated. So **rEFInd** isn't even need here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that you updated your answer before posting my last comment.